# How to automatically clean up TeamCity build configurations for merged dev (feature) branches?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

Looking for a process to disable and archive CI jobs on DEV branches that have merged to production and are no longer needed.

Currently our process is:

1. After a release, find out which branches will be in the next release
2. Set up jobs for those branches
3. When the next release occurs, check with the developer of the branch to confirm completion

This is very manual and somewhat simple. If anyone else has ideas on how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: What VCS are you using?

Comment: We use MSbuild to build any solutions and run them via command line.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with teamcity?

Comment: MSBuild is an option in the Build Steps of TeamCity. The question was what are some ways to archive TeamCity jobs (for dev branches) once they have been merged to production and are no longer needed.

Comment: OK, so you're building with TeamCity but your source is in TFS, so you can't use TeamCity's automatic feature branch management.